# Which of these version labels is higher?

Tags: language-agnostic, versioning

Bearing in mind that

```
100 > 9
```

and

```
.9 > .100
```

Which of these is the later version?

```
Version 2.1.100
Version 2.1.9
```

I'm trying to figure out whether the dots in a version label act as a decimal point or if they are simply delimiters around independently incrementing numbers.

Comment: "delimiters around independently incrementing numbers" in my experience. So Major version number 2, minor version 1, patch number 9 or 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice seems to have 2.1.9 is before 2.1.100. See for instance

- [Semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)
- [Debian version comparison algorithm](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-version)
- [RPM version comparison algorithm](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/dependencies.html#versioning)

but people tends to do their own thing, especially when considering old enough software (the RPM documentation reference hints that Perl version had such oddity in the past, probably related to the presence of initial 0 in a segment)